# Как проверить в Python, что число являетcя "всесторонним" нечётным числом?

Tags: python-3.x

Всесторонне нечетные числа — это такие числа, все цифры которых нечетны и длина числа нечетна.

Comment: Многовато минусов для первого поста ;) Автор - вас минусуют, потому что вы не показали никаких собственных попыток https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Если вам ответ понятен, примите его https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer, если не всё ясно - задавайте вопросы.

Comment: @MBo, одноразовый аккаунт скорее всего)

Answer (score 5):

```
a=input()

len(a)%2 and all(int(c)%2 for c in a)
```